# I am trying to find the solubility of benzoic acid in different solvents to prepare a liquid-liquid extraction

Tags: acid-base, solubility, extraction

I need to prepare a liquid-liquid extraction using the partition coefficient (K) of benzoic acid in different solvents and water:

```
K ~ solubility of benzoic acid in solvent/solubility of benzoic acid in water
```

Several solvents are offered to me (e.g. ethyl acetate, chloroform,...), and I am trying to find the solubility of benzoic acid in each of those solvents. The problem is that I can't find all of them (e.g. benzoic acid in ethyl acetate). I can't seem to find a database of such solubilities. I would greatly appreciate if someone could please re-direct me to such database. Conversely, can solubility be predicted efficiently?

Thank you very much for your time!!

Answer (score 2):

Funny you're looking at solubility of benzoic acid. A few years ago, there was an [Open Notebook Science challenge](http://onschallenge.wikispaces.com) to measure solubility:

> The first round of this challenge calls upon people with access to materials and equipment to measure the solubility of compounds (aldehydes, amines and carboxylic acids are a priority) in organic solvents and report their findings using Open Notebook Science

So the raw data is available through Google Sheets [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQaHn9ZeRZ2YYoEqUMY5k-k_ks1wYb-nYUllZP8vgT0/edit#gid=0)

There is a [general web service](http://showme.physics.drexel.edu/onsc/models/multisolvent.php) for predicting solubility.

For example, you can predict the solubility of benzoic acid using [Abraham solvation parameters](http://onschallenge.wikispaces.com/Benzoic+acid+-+Abraham)

There used to be a search mechanism, but I'll have to ask the authors - it's been a few years.